# Add row to existing table in Excel with Javascript API

Tags: javascript, excel, office365

Using the Javascript API for Office 365 Web Apps, I'm trying to increase the row count on an existing table without reloading the entire table. Is there a way to increase the row count of a table without getting the entire table, concatenating the row, and then redrawing the table on the sheet? This could turn into a very, very big array, if done that way.

Found the solution on the MSDN boards:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/754a112f-fbca-44d9-8063-74b440a9ca82/add-table-row-to-existing-table-with-the-javascript-api?forum=appsforoffice

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a binding to that table object. Then you can call addrowsasync() to add a new row to the table.